# Gradle read environment specific values from properties.xml

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to manage version number for each environment differently from gradle using productFlavors. I have the following in my properties.xml file

```
<resources>
    <integer name="version.code">100</integer>
    <string name="version.name">1.0.1</string>
</resources>
```

and I wrote the following in my build.gradle file. I expected it to act like switch-case however the following gradle sync error showed me the opposite.

```
productFlavors {

    String path = "res/values/properties.xml";

    prd {
        applicationId "com.company.appname"
        path = "../prd/" + path;
    }

    tst {
        applicationId "com.company.appname.tst"
        path = "../tst/" + path;
    }

    dvl {
        applicationId "com.company.appname.dvl"
        path = "../dvl/" + path;
    }
    qa {
        applicationId "com.company.appname.qa"
        path = "../qa/" + path;
    }

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(path))

    if (propFile.canRead()){
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

        if (props!=null && props.containsKey('version.code') && props.containsKey('version.name')) {
            versionCode props.getProperty('version.code')
            versionName props.getProperty('version.name')
        }
    }

}
```

> ..\qa..\dvl..\tst..\prd\res\values\properties.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

How can I read environment specific version.code and version.name from build.gradle?

Comment: Why are they resources in the first place? Why not just define their values in Gradle, then reference them from `BuildConfig` in your Java code? Also note that `Properties` reads properties files (e.g., `gradle.properties`), not XML. "I expected it to act like switch-case" -- your `build.gradle` file does not build your app. It builds an object model of how to build your app. All product flavors objects will be assembled, which is why things like continually appending to a string will not work well.

Comment: BTW, if you do really need them as resources (e.g., to load in a layout file for your about screen), you can use `resConfig` in Gradle to generate them on the fly.

Comment: I am not using them in code actually. I was using android:versionCode on AndroidManifest for all environments. I decided to use different versions for each environment, and deleted the related fields in manifest. I've added >>versionCode 100 to each environment in productFlavors. 

Everything looks fine, however there are a couple of lines (related to dexguard) has to be commented out in dvl, but has to open in other environments. Changing them before committing all the time doesn't seem best practice. That is the root of problem :)

Comment: @CommonsWare btw I didn't want to create multiple AndroidManifest.xml files for each environment, because for every little change in manifest, all other manifest files has to be changed as well.